# Keycloak with mod-security

Tags: keycloak, mod-security, mod-security2, keycloak-connect

I plan to use Keycloak as our primary login app, but before i move forward with deployment, i need to address one concern. The issue arose when i enabled mod-security on the Apache server. This resulted in several Keycloak screens and operations becoming blocked, including the ability to update the theme. if i disable the mod-security everything works fine

am i doing anything wrong or am i miss some kind of setting for mod-security in keycloak

kindly suggest some solution

I try to disable few rules, but there are too many and also for disabling rule, i need to provide some proper reason to do so.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is nothing to provide any code here, it's plain and simple deploy as is

Answer (score 0):

OWASP ModSecurity Core Rule Set *Dev on Duty* here. Are you using the *Core Rule Set* (CRS)? Are those the rules you are having trouble with, or are you using some other rule set? Please confirm.

Assuming you are using CRS, **have you tuned your WAF installation for your web application** (Keycloak)? Tuning is a *required step* before CRS can be properly and correctly used in front of a web application. This is especially true if using a higher paranoia level, i.e. paranoia level 2 and above.

There are some great guides and documentation available online which cover the tuning process. The [CRS false positives and tuning documentation](https://coreruleset.org/docs/concepts/false_positives_tuning/) is very good. There is also a popular series of [tutorials on netnea.com](https://www.netnea.com/cms/apache-tutorials/) which cover every step from the very beginning: compiling the ModSecurity WAF engine, installing CRS, tuning by writing rule exclusions, and more.